# First character of pointer

Tags: c, pointers, char

I have a question regarding char pointers.

I am reading a file in C, using `fgets`. This is a short overview so you can understand what I would like to do:

```
char configline[configmax_len + 1]; //configmax_len is the max value I need
while(fgets(configline, sizeof(configline), config){ //config is the file
    char *configvalue = strtok(configline, " ");
    if (configvalue[0] == "#"){
        continue;
    }
    …
}
```

`char * configvalue` is a pointer to the current line being read. What I would like to check is if the first character of the line is a "#".

However when I do the if statement: `if (configvalue[0] == "#")`, the compiler throws an error: `comparison between pointer and integer`.

How could I check if the first character of the string a pointer is pointing to is a certain value?

Comment: Compare strings in C with `strcmp()`, not `==` (so `if (strcmp(configvalue, "#") == 0)` might be right).  And `"#"` is a string; if you want to compare the character `'#'` use single quotes, not double quotes (so `if (configvalue[0] == '#')` might be right too).

Comment: thank you jonathan, the last remark helped with the single quotes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try using

```
if (configvalue[0] == '#'){
```

this should compile nicely

Answer (score 6):

Use single quotes to denote a single character; double quotes denote strings, which are represented by a pointer to the first character, hence the error message.

Comment: thank you , that resolved my problem. i would love to vote your answer as helpful, but i dont have enough reputation. :(

Answer (score 1):

Strtok returns a pointer to a nul terminated string, but you're comparing this with a string constant using `==`:

```
if (configvalue[0] == "#")
```

Firstly, `configvalue` is a pointer, so you could do something like:

```
if (*configvalue == '#')
```

To dereference the pointer and get the first character in the output string.